# How to redirect URLs based on query string?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I successfully mass migrated a Wordpress site to Drupal.  Unfortunately in Wordpress, the content URL's were something like www.example.org/?p=123.  My domain is still the same, but I want to do a redirect via `htaccess` as Drupal will not allow URL's to be www.example.org/?p=123.  In other words, the content does not have the same URL as it did in Wordpress.  For example, the new Drupal URL would be something like `www.example.org/content/MyNewPage`

I tried this in my .htaccess file and it does not work

```
Redirect 301 /\?p=375 http://www.example.org/content/MyNewPage
```

So I tried the below, but it does not work either.

```
Redirect 301 /\?p\=375 http://www.example.org/content/MyNewPage
```

Just as a test, I tried the below and it worked.

```
Redirect 301 http://www.example.org http://www.google.com
```

I made sure that my Redirect rule is at the top of the list in my .htaccess so it will be evaluated first.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

neither Redirect nor RedirectMatch allow you to specify a query string for the redirect source.
[[Source]](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/)

You have to use mod-rewrite  for redirecting based on query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^p=375$
RewriteRule (.*)  http://www.example.org/content/MyNewPage?  [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get redirected to a 404 page not found, and my URL is still stuck showing http://www.example.org/?p=375.  I can confirm that the "content/MyNewPage" does exist and works.  I also can confirm that my RewriteRules are working because they work fine in Drupal.

Comment: Clear your browser's cache and try again, browsers cache `301 Permanent redirect`s

Comment: Good suggestion, but now Firefox says that it is redirecting as an endless loop.  "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."  The URL is coming out as http://www.example.org/content/MyNewPage?p=375

Answer (score 1):

You may consider use ModRewrite in your htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^p=345$    [NC]
RewriteRule index.php content/MyNewPage [NC,L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

And you also may want to pass the old page id to the new URL concatenated (or maybe by QS?):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^p=(.*)$    [NC]
RewriteRule index.php content/MyNewPage-%1 [NC,L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```