# WordPress 301 redirect with old/new url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, seo, rewriting

I'm trying to get back my url of an old wordpress without custom permalink to a new version of the same site with goold url but it doesn't work.

I tried 301 redirection of old url to newer...

.htaccess :

```
Redirect 301 /\?page_id=184 http://mydomain.com/about
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Redirection](http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) for this.

This plugin will help you to redirect old urls to target urls.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks ! You saved my life :) This plugin works well.

More explanation : I can't made "redirection 301" with query string. For this I have to use rewrite cond and rewrite rules...

More info there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073253/how-to-redirect-urls-based-on-query-string