# How to redirect to a URL with a query string?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've seen questions regarding redirecting a URL with a query string to a new URL that doesn't contain a query string.

Unfortunately I have to do this in reverse, my knowledge of redirecting in Apache isn't good, and I can't find any information about doing this.

So for example I need to redirect something like:

/news/news-item

to:

/news?item=news-item

The new URL structure is obviously not ideal, but this is something that is out of my control.

I've tried:

`RedirectMatch 301 /news/news-item http://www.example.com/news?item=news-item`

But obviously this doesn't work.

From what I understand I need to use `RewriteRule`, can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm probably to late with my answer, but this is how I would have done it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^news/(.*) /news?item=$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I would also use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`. In case a file or a directory with the specified name exists, it would not procede with the rewrite rule below.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out after a bit of research.

I'm not sure if this is 'ideal' way of doing this, but it seems to work well from my perspective.

Instead of using a `Redirect` of a `RedirectMatch` it's possible to achieve this using `RewriteRule`, something like:

`RewriteRule ^news/?(.*) http://example.com/?posts=list [R=301,L]`

This will redirect any request to `news` or `news/x` (where x could be anything) to:

`http://example.com/?posts=list`

I should have made it clearer in my initial question that the query string didn't need to be generated using part of the old URL, if you need to do this I think you'll need to look into something like this:

[How to redirect URLs based on query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073253/how-to-redirect-urls-based-on-query-string)