# htaccess redirect condition doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I created few redirect conditions but only one among all doesn't work:

```
Redirect 301 /testy.html?task=quiz&quizId=1 /testy-egzaminacyjne/egzaminy-na-pozwolenie-na-bron.html
```

It's probably because first (old) URL uses ? = & ... but I can't figure out how it should be changed correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect URLs based on query string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073253/how-to-redirect-urls-based-on-query-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot match query string using `Redirect` directive. Use `mod_rewrite` instead.

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^task=quiz&quizId=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^testy\.html$ /testy-egzaminacyjne/egzaminy-na-pozwolenie-na-bron.html? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: My redirect rule was created using: http://www.htaccessredirect.net/ . I created about 12 similar rules and all of them works... only above doesn't. I'll give a try to your solution.