# Nginx rewrite: How do I rewite this?

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-location

I've been at this for hours now - nothing works, so here I am.

I have a bunch of files in /pages/ with number filenames, i.e. `123.php`, `321.php`, `111.php` etc.

I need to rewrite the URL so that the content of these files are shown when accessing this URL:

```
example.com/index.php?id={filename-without-.php}
```

So:

`example.com/pages/123.php` => `example.com/index.php?id=123`

`example.com/pages/999.php` => `example.com/index.php?id=999`

I'm doing this to preserve the original URLs.

After a lot of reading and trial/error, I've come up with:

```
location = /pages {
    rewrite ^/pages/([0-9]+)?$.php index.php?id=$1 permanent;
}
```

It still doesn't work, and I can't figure out why not.

If I access `example.com/index.php?id=123` I'm merely redirected to `example.com/?id=123` and the front page of my WordPress install is showing.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated - thank you, thank you.

##########################

Full server-block with all rules:

```
server {
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        listen 130.x.x.x;
        ######## HTTP -> HTTPS redirect ###################
        #set $redirect_var 0;
        #        if ($https = '') {
        #        set $redirect_var 1;
        #        }
        #        if ($redirect_var = 1) {
        #return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
        #        }
        ###################################################
        root /home/example.com/public_html;
        index index.php index.htm index.html;
        access_log /var/log/virtualmin/example.com_access_log;
        error_log /var/log/virtualmin/example.com_error_log;
        fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE nginx;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
        fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
        fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/example.com/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI $document_uri;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /home/example.com/public_html;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT $remote_port;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS $https;
        #location ~ \.php(/|$) {
        #   try_files $uri $fastcgi_script_name =404;
        #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/php-nginx/164846487416392.sock/socket;
        #}
        # htaccess
        #location / {
        #   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        #}
        location /pages {
            rewrite ^/pages/(.*)$.php /index.php?id=$1 permanent;
        }
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        listen 130.x.x.x:443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /home/example.com/ssl.combined;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/example.com/ssl.key;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

please try it without the '=' sign " If an equal sign is used, this block will be considered a match if the request URI exactly matches the location given."

to be like this

```
location /pages {

rewrite ^/pages/(.*)$.php /index.php?id=$1 permanent;

}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your time. Unfortunately, it still just redirects me to example.com/?id=123 and displays the home page. Any ideas?

Comment: can you share the other used rules

Comment: I actually commented them all out to test this, so I can't imagine it being a problem. But yes, I'll include the block in my question. Just a sec

Comment: Added in the full server block. Thank you so much man, for helping me with this. Really appreciate it.

Comment: did you reload Nginx after those edits?

Comment: I've restarted Nginx  every time, using `systemctl restart nginx`

Comment: Do you see anything wrong with the setup as is?