# htaccess url redirect (character "?")

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect

I have a url like this:

```
 http://mydomain.es/foro.php?topic=9
```

And I want to redirect it to:

```
 http://mydomain.es/foro/9/
```

But I can't get it to work, I have tried something like:

```
 redirectMatch  302 ^/foro.php\?topic=([0-9]+)$ /foro/$1/
```

But it don't work, the problem is the character ?, if i remove it in the url (and use a redirectMarch like

```
 redirectMatch  302 ^/foro.phptopic=([0-9]+)$ /foro/$1/)
```

it works fine, can you help me? I'm going crazy.

Answer (score 0):

[answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13073517/4999494) - query strings are not supported by rewritematch. Use mod_rewrite instead.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/?foro\.php\?topic=([^&\s]+) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ /foro/%1? [NE,NC,R,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /foro.php?topic=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```