# Redirections in apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, query-string

I'm trying to perform the following permanent redirection in .htaccess file, but I can not make them work. Can you help me?

Thank you very much. Regards!

Redirect is this:

```
http://www.example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=cavite-multi-channel-office/c1g7x

to 

https://www.example.com/insurance-ph/contact-us/branches/cavite.jsp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to redirect based on the query string I think you can find the answer here: [How to redirect URLs based on query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073253/how-to-redirect-urls-based-on-query-string) :)

So in your case you would get something like:

```
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^_escaped_fragment_=cavite-multi-channel-office/c1g7x$
    RewriteRule (.*)  https://www.example.com/insurance-ph/contact-us/branches/cavite.jsp  [R=301,L]
```