# htaccess query string redirects old page to new page

Tags: string, .htaccess, redirect, opencart

I have been reading quite a bit but no luck :(

So it goes like this:

The old pages were like this:
*http://www.website.co.uk/category/subcat/page.php?id=AB-GRKIS1515*

*They now need to be redirected to:
http://www.website.co.uk/category/some-seoenabled-url*

If it helps on the new pages I am using Opencart.

It seems that I need to use htaccess query string redirects, but all my attempts have failed.

Much appreciated, any help!

Comment: Can we see your attempts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect URLs based on query string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073253/how-to-redirect-urls-based-on-query-string)

Comment: Thanx billynoah, that helped finding the solution as per your link. I'll post the answer found shortly. Ta very much.

Answer (score 0):

The solution found with Billy's help is as follows:

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^id=AB-GRKIS1515$
RewriteRule (.*)  http://www.website.co.uk/category/some-seoenabled-url?  [R=301,L]

Super happy today ;o)

Alex