# Redirect / Rewrite with .htaccess of an url containing :

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to redirect from `/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&task=category&id=44:pinco` to `google.it`

Note the special char :

But it doesn't seem to work.

This is one of the tests I've tried. Where am I wrong?

```
redirect 301 /?option=com_k2&view=item&id=44:pinco http://www.google.it
```

Comment: _“Where am I wrong?”_ - in your understanding of what the documentation means when it says _“URL-path”_ ...

Comment: @CBroe: do you mean that the path should be absolute?

Comment: Or that it's not possible to parse the entire query string?

Comment: The _path_ component of the URL is the only thing that gets checked against here - and that is just `index.php`. If you want to do anything based on the query string, then you need to use mod_rewrite (RewriteCond to check query string contents, followed by a RewriteRule to then redirect elsewhere based on the condition.)

Comment: @CBroe: thanks. But how can I achieve it with the Rewrite?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect URLs based on query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073253/how-to-redirect-urls-based-on-query-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not redirect Query String using `Redirect` directive. You need to check Query String using `℅{QUERY_STRING}` variable.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond ℅{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_k2&view=itemlist&task=category&id=44:pinco$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://google.it? [L,R]
```