# RewriteRule is not being applied

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have theses rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule materia/([^/]+)/?$ article.php?slug=$1 [QSA,NC]
  RewriteRule busca/?s=([^/]+) search.php?s=$1 [QSA,NC]
  RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?slug=$1 [QSA,NC]
</IfModule>
```

But the second rewrite rules is not being applied when the URL is something like http://website.test/busca/?s=teste

htaccess tester: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=28e2b25d-f6ef-5faa-a5c6-a412a87d5523

Comment: RewriteRule matches against the _path_ component of the URL only. If you want to do anything based on the query string, you need to do that with a RewriteCond. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073253/how-to-redirect-urls-based-on-query-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several mistakes here:

1. to match a *query string* (`?s=xxx`), you need to use a `RewriteCond` on `%{QUERY_STRING}`
2. `RewriteCond` scope is for very next rule **only**. In your case, it only checks if it's not an existing folder/file for the first rule.
3. Use `L` flag after each rule, unless you know what you're doing.
4. Use a `RewriteBase` or absolute paths.
5. `QSA` flag is not necessary when you rewrite *manually* the query string. All it does is to append the query string (before the rewrite) to the rewrite target.

All-in-one, here is how your rules should look like

```
RewriteEngine On

# Don't touch existing folders/files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^materia/([^/]+)/?$ /article.php?slug=$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s= [NC]
RewriteRule ^busca/?$ /search.php [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanations @Justin Iurman. I have justa another question. I need to add a `RewriteBase /site/`. But adding this line after `RewriteEngine On` don't make any change. The rules are skipping it.

Comment: If you use a `RewriteBase` then remove leading `/`'s for each `RewriteRule` target