# redirect 301 url htaccess /do.php?id=15 to download15.html

Tags: .htaccess, url

I hope everyone is fine.
I want to convert links like this  /do.php?id=15   to /download15.html
I applied this step but it doesn't work
Redirect 301 /do.php?id=15 /download401.html

Comment: The Redirect directive matches against the path component of the URL only, you can not match on specific query string contents with that. You need to use mod_rewrite for this, a combination of RewriteCond and RewriteRule.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073253/how-to-redirect-urls-based-on-query-string