# Redirect URL which have a dynamic ending in htacess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to redirect sevaral URL which have this pattern

`domain.com/cat1/cat2/?customize_changeset_uuid=2af74ec4-ebea-450c-ab57-386390c941ae&customize_autosaved=on`

to

`domain.com/cat1/cat2`

So basically iIneed to strip away everything that comes after the /?customize_changeset

The numbers are changing. I figured that this should go into .htaccess, but can't get it working

My tries:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/?customize(.*)$ $1
```

If I do it like this, it also doesn't work

```
Redirect 301 domain.com/cat1/cat2/?customize_changeset_uuid=2af74ec4-ebea-450c-ab57-386390c941ae&customize_autosaved=on domain.com/cat1/cat2/
```

Then i tried this snippet

```
ErrorDocument 505 example.com
```

without success

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your tried .htaccess rules file in your question as your efforts, Thank you.

Comment: I am struggeling with that. I cam up with something that is probably pretty wrong: RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/?customize(.*)$ $1

Comment: There is nothing wrong or right in efforts, we all are here to learn. Please do edit your question with your efforts, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect URLs based on query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073253/how-to-redirect-urls-based-on-query-string)